# The mind experiment of rebirh

Tags: rebirth

Assume that the earth destroyed just a fraction of second as a result of massive meteoroid collision and there are only 10000 humans live at the moment. A one human being possess strong qualifications to get the rebirth as human again.(karmic effects,exact "chuthi citta" at the moment of death and etc....). So what happen next as there are no conditions to get the rebirth as human again?

Answer (score 1):

Human realm is not the only realm of existence. There are [31 in total](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html). Also, it doesn't say that earth is the only place in the universe where humans live. So the person could be born in another human realm or the closest thing to it.

In any case, it's a purely hypothetical situation. I doubt that a meteoroid can destroy the earth in fraction of a second. Someone will probably have to instantly place the earth on the sun or in a black hole for such a thing to  happen.

Comment: Answer is superficial and based on assumptions as you mention the earth is the only place in the universe where humans live.

Comment: The question is superficial and based on many assumptions and I did not say that earth is the only place where humans live. Read again.

Comment: sorry. yes you have mention there are other places in universe where human lives. So what are those planets in universe?

Comment: sorry. yes you have mention there are other places in universe where  human lives. So what are those planets in universe?  it's a purely hypothetical situation- yes that's why I have mention this is a mind experiment. Also you are confirming existence of life in universe except of earth as mention in scriptures. My aim of question is how do you implement  or apply rebirth.

Comment: My meteoroid example is just to describe that existence of humans and other form of life forms completely wiped out from earth.( similar to extinction of dinosaurs.)

Comment: Earth is getting destroyed at the end of every Kalpa and it is reformed. Still the humans move on. Read the Sapta Suriya Sutta and the Agganna Sutta.

Answer (score 1):

In A.N. Tikanipāta [Cūḷanīsutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=20&A=5985&w=%E2%C5%A1%B8%D2%B5%D8&eng=metta_e):

> 10. **Cūlanikāsuttaṃ** –– The thousandfold world system
>
> Venerable Ānanda approached the Blessed One, worshipped, sat on a side and said to the Blessed One: Venerable sir, these words I heard
>   from the Blessed One and are acknowledged by the Blessed One: Ānanda,
>   Abhibhū, a disciple of the Blessed One Siki makes announcements to the
>   thousandfold world systems at one and same time from the world of
>   Brahma. Venerable sir, the Blessed One worthy and rightfully
>   enlightened, making an announcement how far could you be heard?
>
> Ānanda, he is a disciple of an immeasurable number of Thus Gone Ones.
>
> For the second time venerable Ānanda said: Venerable sir, these words
>   I heard from the Blessed One and are acknowledged by the Blessed One:
>   Ānanda, Abhibhū, a disciple of the Blessed One Siki makes
>   announcements to the thousandfold world systems at one and same time
>   from the world of Brahma. Venerable sir, the Blessed One worthy and
>   rightfully enlightened, making an announcement how far could you be
>   heard?
>
> Ānanda, he is a disciple of an immeasurable number of Thus Gone Ones.
>
> For the third time venerable Ānanda said : Venerable sir, these words
>   I heard from the Blessed One and are acknowledged by the Blessed One:
>   Ānanda, Abhibhū, a disciple of the Blessed One Siki makes
>   announcements to the thousandfold world systems at one and same time
>   from the world of Brahma. Venerable sir, the Blessed One worthy and
>   rightfully enlightened, making an announcement how far could you be
>   heard?
>
> Ānanda, have you heard of the Cūlanika thousandfold world system?
>
> Venerable sir, Blessed One, Well Gone One, now is the time to hear it.
>   The bhikkhus hearing it from the Blessed One will bear it .
>
> Then Ānanda, listen and attend carefully, I will tell.
>
> The Blessed One said: Ānanda, as long as the moon and sun illuminate
>   the directions, till then the thousandfold world systems will prevail,
>   with a thousand, moons, suns, Mahameru mountains, Indian peninsulars,
>   Aparagoyanas, Uttarakurus, Pubhavidehas, fourfold oceans, fourfold
>   rulers, fourfold guardian kings, heavens of the thirty-three, heavens
>   of Titan gods, heavens of happiness, heavens of the gods of creation,
>   heavens of the gods who create others, worlds of Brahma. Ānanda, to
>   this is called the thousandfold Cūlanika world system. Ānanda, as long
>   as the thousandfold Cūlanika world system prevails till then the
>   thousandfold world system, calls this the two thousandfold middle
>   world system. Ānanda, as long as the two thousandfold middle world
>   element prevails till then the thousandfold world system calls this
>   the three thousandfold and the great thousandfold world system.
>   Ānanda, if the Thus Gone One desires, he announces to the three
>   thousandfold and the great thousandfold world system.
>
> Venerable sir, how does the Blessed One, if he desires announce to the
>   three thousandfold and the great thousandfold world system?
>
> Here Ānanda, the Thus Gone One pervades the three thousandfold and the
>   great thousandfold world system with an effulgent light, so that those
>   sentient beings see it, then the Thus Gone One makes a sound. In this
>   manner an announcement is made to the three thousandfold and the great
>   thousandfold world system if he desires.
>
> When this was said venerable Ānanda said to venerable Udayi: It is
>   great gain for me that my Teacher is so powerful.
>
> When this was said venerable Udayi said: Friend Ānanda, what does it
>   matter to you, when your Teacher is so powerful?
>
> Udayi, do not say so. If Ānanda passes away without freeing his mind
>   from greed, on account of that pleasant mind, he will be ruler of gods
>   for a hundred times. In this same peninsular of India he will be the
>   ruler. Yet Udayi Ānanda will extinguish in this same life.